# PHP strip a string

Tags: php, string

I have a string in PHP (`$string`) and I'd like to remove all:

- Numbers
- Spaces
- Commas

What's the best and simplest way to go about this?

Comment: [Documentation is your friend.  Look at it.  Love it.  Use it.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: @JackManey While I wholeheartedly agree with the general sentiment, if the OP is unfamiliar with regex, finding that manual page probably wouldn't be much help.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions

```
$str = preg_replace('/\d|\s|,/', '', $str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/[\d\s,]/', '', $str);
```

Looking at a [regular expression tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) might be a good idea to, if you're planning on working with regular expressions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression replace function:

```
$string = preg_replace('#[\d\s,]#', '', $string);
```

You can find a lot of information about the regular expression syntax here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('#( pm|[0-9 ]+)#', '', $string);
```

*Edit:* The OP originally asked for the phrase " pm" to also be removed, and didn't include commas.

Comment: @Shiplu:  The OP asked for the phrase " pm" to be removed.  He has modified his question and removed this since then.

Answer (score 0):

The most effient way to do this is using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$string = 'Hello, World! abc123abc';
$match  = '123456789, '; // All characters that should be removed
$result = str_replace(str_split($match), '', $string);
// $result = 'HelloWorld!abcabc';
```

What this does, is first to split the string `'123456789, '` into an array of all the characters (`array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ',' ' ')`) and use `str_replace()` to replace each of the array values with an empty string.

IMHO, this is also the easiest way to do this if you are unfamiliar with regular expressions (functions like [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace)), and is also faster than its regex equivalents (2.75 seconds per 1 million operations for `str_replace()` vs. 4.15 for `preg_replace()` on my computer).